# How do I request a PR review from GitHub users that can accept my pull request?

Tags: github, pull-request

I am comfortable using git CLI, but I'm still a novice at the github UI, PR concept, and github etiquette.

[I created a pull request](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/pull/144) and I haven't received any feedback on it (except for some positive emojis). I have no special permissions in this repository. I'm not a contributor, member, owner, etc. I'm just a random GitHub user that submitted a PR request.

Here are my questions, in order:

1. After enough time has passed (~5 months in this case), is it bad form to ping GH users capable of merging my PR to request a review?
2. Is there a way to ping the group of GH users in that repository that are capable of merging my PR? e.g., `@members` or something.
3. Is there a way to find the list of GH users capable of merging my PR, ideally sorted by most recent activity GitHub activity, so I can ping 1 or 2 of them to review my PR?

I only need the details of the first question that's a "Yes."

Comment: Any user who is [in this list](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/commits/master/) with a commit message starting with "Merge pull request" should be able to merge it. Given that the last commit was 7 years ago, I wouldn't hold your breath. Seems to be only addyosmani, EvanCarroll, and jrburke.

Comment: @NickODell I'll definitely use this if there's no better way. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, there's multiple 7 year old pull requests. If you do get a response you could try to negotiate for write access so you can make more changes.

Comment: "I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to get from that list to a user's profile so I can see their latest GH activity." Hover over username -> brings up card -> click username in card.

Comment: @NickODell Oh, duh. I've done that before in other places. Thanks again!